# How to define a callable derivative function

Tags: python-3.x

For a project I am working on, I am creating a class of polynomials that I can operate on. The polynomial class can do addition, subtraction, multiplication, synthetic division, and more. It also represents it properly.

For the project, we are required to do create a class for Newton's Method. I was able to create a callable function class for f, such that

```
>f=polynomial(2,3,4)
>f
2+3x+4x^2
>f(3)
47
```

I have a derivative function `polynomial.derivative(f)` outputs `3+8x`.

I want to define a function labeled `Df` so that in my Newtons Method code, I can say, `Df(x)`. It would work so that if x=2:

```
>Df(2)
19
```

Comment: By the way, if `f` is a `polynomial` object, you can omit the `polynomial.` and just say `f.derivative()`.   Why can't you say `Df=f.derivative(); Df(2)`

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of a polynomial is still a polynomial. Thus, instead of returning the string `3+8x`, your `polynomial.derivative` function should return a new `polynomial`.

```
class polynomial:
   def __init__(c, b, a):
       self.coefs = [c, b, a]

   [...]
   def derivative(self):
       return polynomial(*[i*c for i,c in enumerate(self.coefs) if i > 0], 0)
```

Hence you can use it as follow:

```
> f = polynomial(2, 3, 4)
> Df = f.derivative()
> f
2+3x+4x^2
> Df
3+8x+0x^2
> f(3)
47
> Df(2)
19
```

---

### Edit

Of course, it is `enumerate` and not `enumerates`. As well, the `__init__` misses the `self` argument. I code this directly on SO without any syntax check.

Of course you can write this in a `.py` file. Here is a complete working example:

```py
class Polynomial:
    def __init__(self, c, b, a):
        self.coefs = [c, b, a]
        self._derivative = None

    @property
    def derivative(self):
        if self._derivative is None:
            self._derivative = Polynomial(*[i*c for i,c in enumerate(self.coefs) if i > 0], 0)
        return self._derivative

    def __str__(self):
        return "+".join([
            str(c) + ("x" if i > 0 else "") + (f"^{i}" if i > 1 else "")
            for i, c in enumerate(self.coefs)
            if c != 0
        ])

    def __call__(self, x):
        return sum([c * (x**i) for i, c in enumerate(self.coefs)])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Polynomial(2, 3, 4)
    print(f"f: y={f}")
    print(f"f(3) = {f(3)}")
    print(f"f': y={f.derivative}")
    print(f"f'(2) = {f.derivative(2)}")
```

```
f: y=2+3x+4x^2
f(3) = 47
f': y=3+8x
f'(2) = 19
```

You can rename the property with the name you prefer: `derivative`, `Df`, `prime`, etc.

Comment: My  derivative function returns a polynomial, so that `polynomial.derivative(f)(2)` is `19`. My function also strips away any term with a zero coefficient.

Comment: I presume `enumerates` should be `enumerate`.

Comment: Is there a way to include this in the .py file, as my Newtons Method Definition requires a Df. This seems to require the user plugs this into the console/interpreter.

Comment: @CrockyCrockidile I do not understand your request. Of course, any code written in the interpreter can be put inside a `.py` file.